# No output from process running in background from shell script

Tags: python, linux, bash, shell

I wrote a small script to test some servers in a docker container.

```
#!/bin/bash
echo started
python /opt/server.py &
nginx -g 'daemon off;'
```

The python server writes some information that we need to see but it doesnt show up when I run `docker run -P image` or if I run `docker run -dP image` and check with docker logs.

The python server uses `print` and `sys.stdout.write`. Both dont show up
I tried redirecting the output `python /opt/server.py >&1` and /dev/stdout. Neither worked. Logs from nginx are fine. The docker image symlinks the access logs to /dev/stdout.

I looked in /proc/#/fd/1 for each proccess running and theyre all pointing to the same pipe

`l-wx------ 1 root root 64 Dec 15 21:18 1 -> pipe:[28195]` from ls

Im not sure how to get this working.

Comment: Ideally, use logging in python instead of print. Otherwise redirect to a file and then read that with `tail -f`.

Comment: Yeah thats true we could do that and probably will I guess now. Seems like a little bit of overhead to just prototype something. I was hoping theres reason why print isnt working in this case. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Does `server.py` look something like this?

```
import time
while True:
   print('something')
   time.sleep(1)
```

Python does something weird when you print and sleep inside a while loop inside containers. To make it work, you need to manually flush the looped print statements:

```
import time
import sys
while True:
   print('something')
   sys.stdout.flush()
   time.sleep(1)
```